# Assigning unique IDs to String using MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, uniqueidentifier, apache-zookeeper

I want to run a MapReduce Job where I want to scan multiple columns from a given file and assign a unique ID(Index No.) to each distinct value for each column. The main challenge is to share the same ID for same value that is encountered on different node or different instances of Reducer.

Currently, I am using zookeeper for sharing the Unique IDs, but that is having its performance  impact. I have even kept the information in local cache's at reducer level to avoid multiple trips to zookeeper for same value. I wanted to explore if there is any other better mechanism to do the same.

Comment: can you use md5(value) as the id?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two possible solutions for your problem

1. Create unique ID based on your value. This might be a hash function with low collision  rate.
2. Use faster storage than ZooKeeper. You can try simple key value storage like Redis to store value to id mapping.